# Is there a way to completely disable all Bixby functionality without rooting the S9+?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, samsung-bixby

I would like to get rid of Bixby altogether and preferably reassign the Bixby hardware button to a different function.

Is that at all possible and if so: how?

Comment: I don't know if its the same as the s9+. Try swiping to the left-most home screen on your Galaxy S9. You should then see the bixby home options thing. Just select the settings cog. There should be a disable option within.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-completely-disable-bixby) has a useful guide to disabling bixby.

> **Disable Bixby Voice**
>
> Go to Bixby home. Click the three vertical dots then settings. Uncheck Bixby Voice
>
> **Disable Bixby Button**
>
> Go to Bixby home. Click the cog. Uncheck Bixby Key
>
> **Remove Bixby from Home screen**
>
> From home screen, hold down on empty space. Swipe right until you see Bixby home screen. Uncheck Bixby Home.

This other [article](https://saintlad.com/remap-bixby-button-on-galaxy-s9/) covers remapping Bixby button. You will have to keep the button enabled. Skip step two in the previous article.

This one is longer, but basically you download an app that will remap the key to what ever action that can be done.

**EDIT**

As of Android Pie (9.0), this guide is no longer accurate to disable Bixby. The Bixby button can still be remapped using bxActions(free) or [Tasker beta](https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-beta-remap-bixby-button/)(paid)(thanks beeshyams) and Bixby Home can be removed from the home screen. However, disabling Bixby completely will most likely require removing via ADB or possibly using [Package Disabler Pro+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elmklmsamsung.batteryaddon)(Paid app).

Comment: I went with bxActions (Pro, i.e. paid) to reward the author. Also hooked up the phone to my Linux Mint and issued the `adb` commands to execute a few shell scripts included in bxActions (they also provide a canned solution for Windows), so that the effect is more permanent. Without those it didn't work reliably. Ever since, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can done. I recently [updated guide to remove Bixby](https://www.darpandodiya.com/code/guide-remove-bixby-bloatware-from-samsung-galaxy-phones/) using adb.

Assuming you've adb installed on your machine, you can run following command to get packages related to Bixby.

```
adb shell pm list packages | findstr "bixby"
or
adb shell pm list packages | grep "bixby"
```

Next step is to uninstall those packages for the current user (that is you). An example for one of the packages:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.samsung.android.bixby.agent
```

Do this for all packages and you will have everything related to Bixby removed from your device. I just verified with my S10 Plus device and it works fine.

One caveat is: The application is being uninstalled for the current user (`--user 0`) – not system wide. Root access it needed to do system wide un-installation. This could also mean that whenever you’ll upgrade or factory reset your device, the bloatware would kick in again. Also button remapping might also not be possible.

If this sounds very technical to you, you may want to read the [guide](https://www.darpandodiya.com/code/guide-remove-bixby-bloatware-from-samsung-galaxy-phones/) for step by step instructions.

Comment: Of course something like `findstr` is rather system-dependent, but thanks for taking the time to write an answer.