# Disable Bixby on Galaxy S9 without root?

Tags: 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9, samsung-bixby

I have read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205042/is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-all-bixby-functionality-without-rooting-the) and realised that it is outdated.

With the most recent android update for my Galaxy S9, I have no way to disable the Bixby button out of the box. Previously I had to sign in to Bixby, Then go to setting and disable the button there. Afterwards I could remove the samsung account and had no issues at all.

**How can I get rid of Bixby/disable the bixby button without rooting the device?**

---

Software update: G960FXXU2CSB9/G960FOXM2CSB3/G960FXXU2CSB3

Android version: 9

Security Patch: 2019-02-01

Bixby Home Version 3.0.02.6

Bixby Voice Version 2.1.04.18

Comment: I bought a flex case for my S9 and used a razor to saw off the case's raised button. No Bixby here unless I want it. Also, I don't have or want a Samsung account. Don't know why anyone would want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the Bixby button by using 
[Bixbi Button Remapper - bxActions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.bxactions&hl=en_US). This allows you to remap the button to another action.

As for disabling Bixby altogether, I am unsure of how to do it.

Another mention was enabling developer options, then scrolling to the bottom of that menu to Background Check, then disabling the options for Bixby in there. I did try this, but it did not disable the Bixby Button, nor am I sure it actually did anything with Voice.

You can still remove Bixby Home by holding on the main screen then navigating over and disabling Home.

Comment: bxActions seems to work, though bixby still pops up very briefly on double click. I also tried the developer options and had no success as well

Answer (score 0):

I have just jumped straight from Android 8 on an S7 to Android 12 on an S10+, so I don't know if this works on any other version than 12:

1. Go to: Settings > Apps > Bixby Voice
2. Select "Disable"

After this, the button appears to do nothing.

---

Similarly, disabling the "Google" app appears to prevent that popping up after a long-press on the home "button".